No logro usar certificado .pem en localhost con php
Quiero conectarme a un API de pasarela de pagos, pero obtengo problemas con el certificado ssl tanto en localhost como en un servidor que tengo contratado para produccion:
Error en la solicitud cURL: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Este es el codigo:
  public function login($service) {
  

        $url = 'https://sandbox-tokener.blumonpay.net/oauth/token';

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/wamp/bin/php/php8.0.26/extras/ssl/cacert.pem");
   
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 99990,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,       
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(['grant_type' => 'password' ,'username' => 'user@user.com','password'=>'pass']), 
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization: Basic Ymx1bW9uX3BheV9jb3JlX2FwaTpibHVtb25fcGF5X2NvcmVfYXBpX3Bhc3N3b3Jk'
            ),
        ));
        try
        {
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            if ($response === false) {
                // Manejo del error
                echo "Error en la solicitud cURL: " . curl_error($curl);
            }
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            // Manejo de la excepción
            echo "Se produjo un error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
}

como veran descargue el archivo .pem de internet y ya lo estableci en el archivo php.ini y en el archivo de configuracion de Apache. Uso php 8.
